# How do I request an API token with httr?

Tags: python, r, python-requests, httr

I'm using `httr` to query the [Open Targets API](https://www.targetvalidation.org/documentation/api#fairusageandapikeys).

I received my API credentials (app_name and secret) and I'm now trying to request a token by attempting to translate the provided instructions for Python:

```
import requests  
API='https://www.targetvalidation.org/api/latest/'

jwt = requests.get(API + 'public/auth/request_token',  
                     params={'app_name':<appname>,'secret':<secret>})

print(jwt.json())
```

Here's what I tried with R and httr:

```
library(httr)
app_name <- "myappname"
secret <- "mysecret"
token <-
 GET("https://www.targetvalidation.org/api/latest/public/auth/request_token", app_name = app_name, secret = secret)
token <- GET("https://www.targetvalidation.org/api/latest/public/auth/request_token", add_headers(app_name = app_name, secret = secret))
token <- GET("https://www.targetvalidation.org/api/latest/public/auth/request_token", config = list(app_name = app_name, secret = secret))

# In all cases, this is what I get
token
# Response [https://www.targetvalidation.org/api/latest/public/auth/request_token]
#  Date: 2017-04-24 08:24
#  Status: 400
#  Content-Type: application/json
#  Size: 60 B
# {"message": {"app_name": "app name [appname] is required"}}
```

What is the right `httr` syntax to request this token?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the parameters as `query`, as explained in the [httr quickstart](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/vignettes/quickstart.Rmd#the-url-query-string):

```
token <- 
GET("https://www.targetvalidation.org/api/latest/public/auth/request_token", 
 query=list(app_name = app_name, secret = secret)
)
```