# Why does the httr package in r always give the same access token?

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, access-token, httr, refresh-token

I have data in a Microsoft Dataverse that I'm attempting to pull into R. I don't have much background in software development / APIs / OAuth so I first used a tutorial that showed me how to work with APIs in Postman. I then used several tutorials online (most notably [this one](https://blog.r-hub.io/2021/01/25/oauth-2.0/#secret-access-token-secret-refresh-token)) to try to replicate what I'm doing in Postman. Doing so, I came up with the code below:

```
require(httr)
require(rvest)

dataverse_api = oauth_endpoint(request = NULL, 
   authorize = https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED/oauth2/v2.0/authorize,
   access = https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED/oauth2/v2.0/token,
   base_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resourcehttps://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com)

API.Key = "REDACTED"
API.Secret = "REDACTED"

App = oauth_app("EPS Project Development", key = API.Key, secret = API.Secret)

API.token = oauth2.0_token(dataverse_api, App, scope = https://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com/.default)
API.AuthKey = API.token$credentials$access_token

GET.Buildings = GET(https://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/crfd0_dartbuildingses, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", API.AuthKey, sep = " ")))
```

The first day, the code above worked, and I was **so excited!** The next day, with no changes to the code, it returned a response of 401 (unauthorized). I've been going back and forth between Postman and R trying to figure out what's different, and what I realized is that every time I authenticate in Postman, I get a completely new access token (as expected); however, in R, when I keep running this code, the parameter stored in `API.token$credentials$access_token` is the same. I'm not really sure why this is.

Doing some more research, it seems like maybe I need a refresh token? I don't understand that because this is the same code other developers posted and no one else seems to be mentioning that it will only work once and then never again without a refresh token. Moreover, inspecting the documentation for httr makes it seem as if part of the oauth2.0_token function is to check whether or not the token needs to be refreshed. Anyway, when I look at the parameter `API.token$refresh()`, it tells me `Error: Refresh token not available`.

So now I'm attempting to get a refresh token, again without really understanding why. The documentation on the httr package details a function called [oauth-refresh](https://rdrr.io/cran/httr/src/R/oauth-refresh.R#sym-refresh_oauth2.0), but `?oauth-refresh` gives an error and `?oauth_refresh` says no results found. I also looked into [this package by MatthewJWhittle](https://rdrr.io/github/MatthewJWhittle/getarc/man/refresh_token.html) that has a function called refresh_token, but again the help functions turn up no results after installing the package, so I guess it's no longer a valid package.

**TLDR: Why is my code coming back with the same access token every time I request authorization? Did I miss a step in the code where I'm supposed to request a refresh token? Or if this is by design, how do I get a new one once this one expires?**

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583351/how-do-i-request-an-api-token-with-httr

Comment: Thanks NelsonGon, but that post isn't really relevant. That person's API doesn't appear to be using OAuth 2.0. And also, my request works fine... it just returns the same key every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to add `cache = FALSE` so  that I'm not using cached tokens. If it's helpful to anyone, the full code is now:

```
require(httr)
require(rvest)

dataverse_api = oauth_endpoint(request = NULL, 
   authorize = https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED/oauth2/v2.0/authorize,
   access = https://login.microsoftonline.com/REDACTED/oauth2/v2.0/token,
   base_url = https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resourcehttps://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com)

API.Key = "REDACTED"
API.Secret = "REDACTED"

App = oauth_app("EPS Project Development", key = API.Key, secret = API.Secret)

API.token = oauth2.0_token(dataverse_api, App, scope = https://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com/user_impersonation, cache = FALSE)
API.AuthKey = API.token$credentials$access_token

GET.Buildings = GET(https://org593dc393.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/crfd0_dartbuildingses, add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", API.AuthKey, sep = " ")))
```